# Can I add a dependent crate that is a subdirectory in a git repository?

Tags: git, rust, rust-cargo

I want to use an EDN parser but it is inside https://github.com/mozilla/mentat. https://github.com/mozilla/mentat/tree/master/edn has its own Cargo.toml.

I tried this:

```
[dependencies]
edn = { git = "https://github.com/mozilla/mentat/tree/master/edn" }
```

But it doesn't work.

Is it possible to add dependency to this crate inside the mentat repository?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [the Cargo documentation](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html):

> Cargo will fetch the git repository at this location then look for a `Cargo.toml` for the requested crate **anywhere** inside the git repository (**not necessarily at the root**).

(*emphasis mine*)

This means that you can just say:

```
[dependencies]
edn = { git = "https://github.com/mozilla/mentat" }
```

Comment: is this even the right answer?

Comment: @Dinesh Does it not work for you? Or what do you mean?

Comment: sorry my bad. There was a typo in the git URL I was trying. This does work!