# How to use latest couchbase-rs version from GitHub

Tags: rust, couchbase, rust-cargo

I want to use latest couchbase-rs version directly from github.

I managed successfully the `couchbase` dependency with:

```
couchbase = { git = "https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-rs", branch = "master"}
```

But I'm not able to use the `couchbase-sys` because it is a subdir of the [couchbase-rs](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-rs) github project.

Is there a way to configure such dependency into `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Can I add a dependent crate that is a subdirectory in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46786956/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not sure that answers it because there are two crates in the same repo.

Comment: @PeterHall but it works, no? Cargo scans through the entire repo looking for a matching Cargo.toml.

Comment: @PeterHall I just compiled with `[dependencies]
couchbase = { git = "https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-rs", branch = "master" }
couchbase-sys = { git = "https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-rs", branch = "master" }` and it worked fine.

Comment: @Shepmaster Oh yes, you are right. I forget that the LHS is the exact crate name. I always feel like that's just a label, which you could use to rename the crate even. Which was discussed but never done. It really _should_ work that way IMO.

Comment: I compiled with `couchbase-sys = { git = "https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-rs", branch = "master", features = ["build-lcb"]}` without success: `thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not find include path from pkg config', libcore/option.rs:914:5`

Comment: @attdona I can not reproduce this behavior. Looks like you [haven't installed a required dependency](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-rs/blob/41ceed4e30ab13a3acd960cac12e2633c01a31af/couchbase-sys/build.rs#L35-L44).

Comment: Many thanks @shepmaster. Was a conflicting couchbase version installed on my machine.