# How to use Apache Arrow's Datafusion 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT as a dependency in a Cargo project?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

On the [git repository](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/d4dc8ba81990233097ac644ff1e1dc0173a9f362/rust/datafusion) for Datafusion, it says  to add the following to the Cargo.toml file to use it as a library:

```
[dependencies]
datafusion = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

I get this as an output when running `cargo build`

```
 Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `datafusion = "^1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"`
  candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.17.0, 0.16.0, 0.15.1, ...
  location searched: crates.io index
required by package `hello_cargo v0.1.0 (/Users/jay/Projects/hello_cargo)`
```

I then tried to use 0.17.0 and ran `cargo +nightly build`:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `arrow-flight v0.17.0`

    Caused by:
      process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/jay/Projects/hello_cargo/target/debug/build/arrow-flight-46000fbc5b8b474b/build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
    --- stderr
    Error: "Failed to locate format/Flight.proto in any parent directory"
    
    warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
    error: build failed
```

It seems to work when I use version 0.16.0

Comment: *Failed to locate format/Flight.proto* seems reasonably self-explanatory of an error message.

Comment: *seems to work* — so... problem solved?

Comment: I'm wondering why having datafusion = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" is not working on its on. Feel like I'm missing something, was hoping someone could illuminate the situation.

Comment: Because [datafusion haven't released version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT yet](https://crates.io/crates/datafusion). You're looking at the README for the future version.

Comment: makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cargo tells you:

```
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.17.0, 0.16.0, 0.15.1, ...
```

There are no versions called `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` of this crate published to crates.io. If you wish to use unreleased code from a git repository, you need to [use a git dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories):

```
[dependencies]
rand = { git = "https://github.com/apache/arrow/" }
```

See also:

- [Can I add a dependent crate that is a subdirectory in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46786956/155423)